# let ./configure find library files in specific directory

Tags: autoconf

I'm currently installing R software on a shared space across several servers. After installation I found that when I login on different servers, R is not guaranteed to run due to the missing of some library files on different machines. 
Here is what I'm trying to do: since the installation of R is machine-dependent, I'd like to put all missing library files like libtermcap.so.2, libg2c.so.1, etc, to a single directory on the shared space, so that when I run ./configure, it will also search for this directory. Since this directory is shared, the installation could become machine-independent, so I won't need to add missing files on each server.

Is there an option to achieve this when I run ./configure? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have copied the library files to `/shared/lib/` and the header files to `/shared/include/`, you can run

```
./configure LDFLAGS=-L/shared/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/shared/include ...other options...
```

Note, however, that you are bound to run into trouble at run time, when you have to convince your installation to use the shared libraries from the right directory, especially in case someone decides to upgrade the default version on the respective host.  That whole business is platform and installation dependent.  I think if your hosts are not at least mostly identical, you ought to install your software (R) locally in a way suitable to the respective system.

Answer (score 0):

Peter's answer is correct (+1), and please take special note of his suggestion to install locally.  Using the local package management system and auto updating on each box is (in the long run) a much easier solution than trying to get compatible binaries/libraries on a shared drive.  To simplify using Peter's solution, note that you can place the appropriate arguments in /shared/share/config.site.  For example:

```
$ cat > /shared/share/config.site << EOF
: ${LDFLAGS=-L/shared/lib}
: ${CPPFLAGS=-I/share/include}
EOF
```

Whenever you run configure with --prefix=/shared, the config.site file will be read and defaults will be set.